# Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("id"))

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: )
In this function it is happening:

```
 loadSingleRestaurant({String restaurantId}) async {
    restaurant = await _restaurantServices.getRestaurantById(id: restaurantId);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

this is the getRestaurantById function:

```
Future<RestaurantModel> getRestaurantById({String id}) =>
      _firestore.collection(collection).document(id).get().then((doc) {
        return RestaurantModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
      });
```

If u need any other info please tell me

Comment: There must be some property in your `doc` that is `null` hence can't be parsed within `RestaurantModel.fromSnapshot(doc);`.

Comment: Did @MiguelRuivo's comment helped solve your issue? Please let us know